# How do I remove an unmounted volume from desktop?

Tags: linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint.

I recently mounted a samba share, done what I wanted then unmounted it again.  Ever since then I have an icon on my desktop that I can't get rid off!

How do I remove it?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you click it & click the DEL key? Or right click & look for a delete option? Or drag it to the trash?

Comment: I did try the DEL key and I right clicked it, but no remove/delete option existed.  After reading your comment I tried dragging it to the trash can, but that still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it should appear as a file in ~/Desktop. So open a terminal and try to delete it from there ...

Comment: No, it doesn't appear in my Desktop folder, even when I type "ls -a".  After further research I used a program called "Disk Image Mounter", but still unable to remove the desktop icon.

Answer (score 1):

Open the system's disk utility (gnome-disks), from there it is possible to remove mountable icons from the desktop.